# When does the event $X=Y$, where $X,Y$ are independent random variables, have positive measure?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent random variables, $X,Y \in [0,\overline{p}]$. If the event $X=Y$ has positive probability, does that mean the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ must have atoms, and at least one atom at the same point? In other words, if the distributions of both $X$ and $Y$ are atomless, can the event $X=Y$ has positive measure?

My approach: If the joint distribution of $(X,Y) \in [0,\overline{p}]^2$ is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure, the event $X=Y$ cannot have positive measure. $H(X,Y)=F(X)G(Y)$ here. Therefore if $F$ and $G$ are both atomless, $H$ must be atomless, therefore absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure. Hence the claim follows.

But I'm not sure if the above reasoning is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: If there are no atoms you can use Fubini to show $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: You mean if there are no atoms in the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ (which are independent) right?